# How to remove whitespaces at a particular region in a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, whitespace

I am trying to remove whitespaces at a particular region in a string to obtain a certain output.

The different sets of string that I have are:

```
gehehntk 45.5 % 43 - 83 5243 /g.mt 25674 - 65748
bin 9.6 md% 346347 - 36537 
tub 31.8 % 3658 - 5585  calci
```

So the output I want is:

```
gehehntk 45.5 % 43-83 5243 /g.mt 25674-65748
bin 9.6 md% 346347-36537 
tub 31.8 % 3658-5585  calci
```

I tried with a regex but was unable to achieve the output:

```
r"\b.*?\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to replace " - " by "-", you can use `replace`

```
s= """Polymorphs 60.3 % 40 - 80 5246 /c.mm 2000 - 7000
Haemoglobin 9.6 gm% 12.0 - 15.0 
PCV 31.8 % 36 - 46  Calculated"""

print(s.replace (" - ", "-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```py
inp = """Polymorphs 60.3 % 40 - 80 5246 /c.mm 2000 - 7000
Haemoglobin 9.6 gm% 12.0 - 15.0 
PCV 31.8 % 36 - 46  Calculated"""

output = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\s+-\s+(\d+)\b', r'\1-\2', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Polymorphs 60.3 % 40-80 5246 /c.mm 2000-7000
Haemoglobin 9.6 gm% 12.0-15.0 
PCV 31.8 % 36-46  Calculated
```